# Create a new instance of a class, based on its "Class"

Tags: java

I believe this can be done using reflection, but in a quick example here's what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a class called "Session" which is a base class (Note: Not an abstract class, as it can be constructed without an extension). I also have a variable stored like so:

```
Class sessionObject = Session.class;
```

Now, Session has a constructor that takes a single parameter, namely an `AsynchronousSocketChannel`. However, the user can change the session object, so for example lets say they have this:

```
public class NewSession extends Session {
    ....
}
```

Then they set `sessionObject = NewSession.class`

Assuming that "Session" and "NewSession" have the same constructors, how would I differentiate between the two and create a new instance based on it's `class`.

Please note, I have tried:

```
sessionObject.getClass().getDeclaredConstructors(AsynchronousSocketChannel.class).newInstance(result);
```

However:

Error:(109, 49) java: method getDeclaredConstructors in class java.lang.Class cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.Class
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assuming that "Session" and "NewSession" have the same constructors, how would I differentiate between the two and create a new instance based on it's class.

`Object.getClass()` returns the `Class` object corresponding to the most derived (specific) types.

So, if you call `getClass()` on an instance of `NewSession`, you will get the `Class` object corresponding to `NewSession`.

You can't create a `Session` object from a `NewSession` constructor or vice versa. So there is no ambiguity to having `getDeclaredConstructors` in `Class`.

> Error:(109, 49) java: method getDeclaredConstructors in class java.lang.Class cannot be applied to given types; required: no arguments found: java.lang.Class reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

The problem is that `getDeclaredConstructors` (note plural) takes no arguments, while `getDeclaredConstructor` accepts a `Class<?>...`. You're probably wanting to use the latter.

Also, as Thomas Shields pointed out, your `sessionObject` is already a `Class`. Thus `getClass()` on it will yield the `Class` for `Class`, rather than the `Class` for `NewSession`.

Answer (score 0):

If `sessionObject` is a `Class` why are you bothering with a `.getClass()` call? Shouldn't:

```
sessionObject.getDeclaredConstructor(AsynchronousSocketChannel.class).newInstance(someAsyncSocketChannelObject);
```

suffice?